# In which files are git aliases stored on OS X?

Tags: macos, git

I am trying to change an alias that I created via

```
git config --global alias.ci commit
```

to

```
git config --global alias.ci commit -m
```

so that I don't have to type it out and to just give the commit a short message each time I do `commit`.

I just migrated from Windows to Mac, and this alias does work on Windows for me. I wonder if it will work on Mac (I assume), and if so: Where can I find the file where these configurations are stored to change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `[alias]`-section in your `~/.gitconfig`-File.

You should find something like

```
[alias]
    ci = commit
```

which you can change to

```
[alias]
    ci = commit -m
```

When using `git config` to change aliases, make sure to put quotes round the command you want to alias if necessary:

```
git config --global alias.ci "commit -m"
```